# Unjar in powershell

Tags: powershell, jar

I'm quite new at using powershell and have a problem.

I want to use a script unjar a .war file and am using this code:

```
jar -xf myjarfile.war
```

But I get an error like:

```
jar : java.io.IOException: META-INF : could not create directory.
```

If I do the same thing in the powershell command windows it works fine, but not when running in a script it doesn't.

Do anyone know what's wrong.

Comment: How and where you invoked your script?

Comment: You got me on the right track! I'm using PowerGUI Script Editor, and when I'm running the script from there I get an error, if I start the script from the shell, it works. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Case closed, thanks Jackie for getting me on track.

When running the script in PowerGUI Script Editor I got the error.

When running the script in the command shell it works fine, I don't need to run it through PGUISE.